# d3.js prevent overwriting of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to program a reusable chart in d3. This works very well so far - I have "encapsulated" the d3 logic in a jquery plugin. However, I have a problem with the d3 events. I would like to attach  mouseover events in the bar chart on each rectangle. My problem: The events will be overwritten -

Example: if I want to display two different bar charts on a page the plugin is called:

```
 $("#firstChart").D3Chart(d3FirstOptions);
 $("#secondChart").D3Chart(d3SecondOptions);
```

plugin-Snippet:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.D3Chart = function (extOpt) {
       //...
    function drawBars() {
      //...
      rect.on("mouseover", function (d) {
             var dpChannel = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
              //...
              });
       }
      //...
    })(jQuery);
```

The mouseover events from the second chart overwrites the events from the first chart 1:1. 
How can I prevent this? I have tried it with a different namespace in the event handler:

```
.on("mouseover.firstchart", ...)
.on("mouseover.secondchart", ...)
```

but that does not help.

How can I solve the problem? thank u!

Comment: Have you seen [Mike's tutorial on reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)?

Comment: yes I have - but what speaks against my implementation?

Comment: It seems to me that the problems you're having shouldn't occur with this pattern.

Comment: you need to put  you code in a jsfiddle & post here so we can figure out